# Convergence of an infinite trig series, preferablay not using approximations

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the trig series
$$ I = \sum_1^{\infty} \sin(\frac{2}{n})-2\sin(\frac{1}{n}).$$
By Taylor series approximation near $0$ one has
$$\sin x \approx x-x^3/3!$$ so that $$I \approx -\sum x^3 $$ which, for $x:= 1/n$ immediately implies the convergence of the series (p-series comparison).

Now I'm not perfectly comfortable with "approximation" techniques. The question is, is there another way of verifying this convergence, without resorting to Taylor series approximation? A more "exact" approach, as apposed to "approximation"?

Much obliged.

Comment: This technique is so simple, why don't you like it? As far as I know, it's the simplest way to prove convergence of series.

Comment: Yes but sometimes it's difficult to guess how may terms of the series you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\sin (\frac 2 n) -2 \sin (\frac  1n)|=|2 \sin (\frac  1n)  \cos (\frac  1n)-2 \sin (\frac  1n)|\leq 2[1-\cos (\frac  1n)]\leq (\frac 1 n)^{2}$ so the series is absolutely convergent.

I have used the inequality $1-\cos x \leq \frac {x^{2}} 2$ valid for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't the last inequality deduced from the Taylor series? It seems to me that at least the first 2 terms of the Taylor series are involved.

Comment: @Erfan You don't need the Taylor series if you accept the elementary fat that $\sin x \leq x$ for all $x \geq 0$. The derivative of $1-\cos x -\frac {x^{2}}2$ is negative and the function vanishes at $0$ so it is $\leq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy You don't even need derivatives if you use $1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac{x}2$. But Erfan might be suspicious concerning $\sin x<x$ for positive $x$, because the RHS is the first term of the Taylor series.  :P